# Add timeout to ping ssh port?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I am going to use the below bash script to ping a remote host's SSH port, which runs correctly:

```
(: </dev/tcp/$vm_ip/22) &>/dev/null
```

Now in some hosts, this command will take very long time (for example 3 minutes) to report failure as the host is down.

I am going to add timeout support for this command and make it return quickly (for example, return in 5 seconds) if the host is not responding.

```
SSH_CMD="(: </dev/tcp/$vm_ip/22) &>/dev/null"
timeout --preserve-status 5 $SSH_CMD
```

However, the above will output an error:

```
timeout: failed to run command ‘(:’: No such file or directory
```

Can you help me on how to fix this?

**==EDIT 1==================**

Tried to change the code like this (without defining the variable):

```
timeout --preserve-status 2 (: </dev/tcp/$vm_ip/22) &>/dev/null
```

The failure is:

```
./test.sh: line 45: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 45: `   timeout --preserve-status 2 (: </dev/tcp/$vm_ip/22) &>/dev/null'
```

Comment: Don't put commands in variables.

Comment: Tried "timeout --preserve-status 2 (: </dev/tcp/$vm_ip/22) &>/dev/null" still failed

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis in your command are shell syntax for a subshell, but `timeout` doesn't run the command it starts through a shell. Instead, it runs it directly. It sees `(:` as the command name and tries to run it, which leads to an error since you're not likely to have such a command in the `PATH`.

You'll need to add an explicit shell there, with something like this:

```
timeout --preserve-status 5 bash -c "(: </dev/tcp/$vm_ip/22) &>/dev/null"
```

Your second command line gives a syntax error because `(` and `)` are special tokens in the shell. That command line would also apply the redirections to `timeout` itself, so the network connection would be opened before `timeout` is even started.

You could quote the words there, i.e. `timeout ... "(:"` etc, but that would only give the same result as `timeout ... $SSH_CMD`.

I'm not exactly sure you need the subshell in there anyway, but you still need to run a shell under `timeout` to have the redirections processed while the timeout is running.

Comment: This one works. I just made a small change.         timeout --preserve-status $ping_timeout bash -c "(: </dev/tcp/$vm_ip/22) &>/dev/null"

Answer (score -1):

Call your old script in your new script like this:

```
timeout --preserve-status 5 name-of-old-script
```